# I turned on compiler optimization and my multithreaded C program imploded aggressively, any articles I can read on this?

Tags: c, multithreading, optimization, compiler-construction, mingw

I'm using MinGW, which is gcc for Windows.  My program involves multiple windows, two different main threads, and several worker threads in a thread pool for overlapped network I/O.

It works perfectly fine without compiler optimization.

A) Is compiler optimization even necessary?  My program's already very fast.  Is it at all likely that it will provide a significant improvement?

B) Are there any articles on how to properly build a multthreaded program so compiler optimization can do its job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

99.9% of all household failures in one optimization mode and not another are due to serious bugs.  Multithreading races etc. are very sensitive to code performance.  An instruction reorder or loop shortcut can turn a test pass into a debugging nightmare.

I'm assuming that the server runs up OK and detonates under load in aparrently different places, so making conventional debugging useless?

You are going to have to rely on logging and changing the test conditions to narrow down the point of ignition.  My guess is this is going to be a Heisenbug that mutates with changes to the code, optimization, options, load profile,  buffer sizes etc.

Not fixing the problem is not a good plan since it wil just show up in another form on next years boxes with more cores etc.  Even with optimization off,  it's still there, lurking, waiting for the opportunity to strike.

I hope I'm providing some comfort.

Seriously - log everything you can with a good logger - one that queues up the logs so as to keep disk latency out of the main app.  Change things around to try and make the bug mutate and perhaps show up in the non-optimized build too.  Write down, (type in),  absolutely everything that you do amd what happens after any change, good or bad.  Making the bug worse is actually better than making its symptoms go away, (without knowing exactly why).  Try the server on various hardware configs, if you can.

Eventually, you will find the bug!

You have one thing going for you - it seems that you can reliably reproduce the problem.  That, in itself, is a massive plus.

Forgot to ask - apart from the nuclear explosive metaphor, what is the main symptom?  Is it AV'ing/segfaulting all over the place, or is it locked or livelocked up?

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll start debugging.  To answer your question the main symptom is that my console-style GUI isn't responding properly (not printing text when it should), and after a few commands it crashes entirely from a segfault.  The program is actually a chat client/server with file transfer which uses overlapped network I/O for educational purposes.

Comment: By "a few commands" I mean a random number of commands between 5 and 20 regardless of which commands I attempt.

Answer (score 5):

“Imploded aggressively” is a bit weird (is your program a controller for a fission bomb?), but I understand that your program behaved as desired without compiler optimizations and mysteriously with compiler optimizations.

The technical term for this is that your program is buggy.

Multithreaded programming is intrinsically hard. Multithreaded programming when the threads share memory is very hard; it's the masochist way of concurrent programming (message passing is a lot easier to get right). You don't just need to read an article or two, you need to read several books and get a few years' programming experience.

You were unlucky that your program seemed to work without optimizations. It probably wouldn't work on a different machine where the timings are a bit different, or with a different compiler, or on a different operating system, either. So you ended up wasting your time thinking your program worked. But it doesn't. A compiler transforms correct source code into correct executables, no matter what optimization level you choose.¹

¹  <sub>Barring compiler bugs, sure. But the odds are very strongly stacked against you.</sub>

Comment: .. or maybe disarmed.. cut the blue wire :)

Comment: Well, now, wait a minute.  Compiler optimization alters code.  It *attempts* to transform correct source code into correct executables, but it's still just a program.  I have tested my program on three very different computers and it has worked 100% okay (without comiler optimization, obviously).  
Is there any reason to believe that just because optimization breaks it--that that axiomatically means it will break in different architectures?

Comment: @SamPorch Yes. It is hundreds if not thousands of times as probable that the bug is in your brand new code rather than in a compiler which has been field-tested to destruction by perhaps millions of users.

Comment: Yes, I see your point.  Upon further research it appears several of my functions weren't thread-safe.  After tracing the paths of execution I found functions (which I had only expected were relevant to one thread) were in fact being used by several threads, and required synchronization.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

To answer part "A" of your question, the unoptimized version of your code still has the concurrency bugs in it, but the timing of how the threads run is such that the bugs have not **yet** been exposed with your test workloads. The current version of the unoptimized program will eventually fail in use, so you will need to fix the concurrency bugs before using the program for real work.

Comment: Actually, it's possible that the machine code that this compiler generate with optimizations turned off has the desired semantics. But the source code is wrong, because its semantics is defined by the language definition, not by what one particular compiler does with one particular set of compilation flags.

Comment: I agree that there is a chance that the machine code might have the correct behavior for code compiled by a particular version of a particular compiler and running on a particular piece of hardware, but for this to happen would be an (un-)fortunate accident. Even things like adding more memory, or a faster disk to the hardware, or running other tasks in addition to the OP's program, could cause OP's program to implode, causing global thermo-nuclear war.